# Swift: binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type "protocol"

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a protocol:

```
protocol ProfileManagerDelegete {
func dataHaveUpdated(type: ReturnType)
```

}

and create a protocol array, and add/remove listener:

```
var listeners: [ProfileManagerDelegete] = []

func addListener(listener: ProfileManagerDelegete) {
    listeners.append(listener)
}

func removeLister(listener: ProfileManagerDelegete) {
    for lis in listeners {
        if lis == listener { // this line error
            //remove listener
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can help ?

Comment: I don't know swift much but I would guess that the `protocol` type needs to implement some sort of equality operator because if it doesn't you can't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have not told Swift how to compare 2 objects of type `ProfileManagerDelegete`. Define a function:

```
protocol ProfileManagerDelegete {
    func dataHaveUpdated(type: ReturnType)
}

func == (lhs: ProfileManagerDelegete, rhs: ProfileManagerDelegete) -> Bool {
    // decide if they are equal
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is that sufficient? I was just looking up the Equatable protocol and making sure that one protocol can inherit from another. I was going to suggest that OP would have to mark his protocol as inheriting from Equatable (as well as write this method).

Comment: Answered my own question by testing. It is indeed sufficient. And trying to inherit Equatable leads to a lot of issues.

Comment: @Just Another Coder, Yes, you are right, but where should i put "==" in, if I put it to protocol. get a error :  Protocol methods may not have bodies

Comment: You should define the `==` function right after the protocol, not inside it. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you want to use the '===' operator. Just make ProfileManagerDelegete conform to AnyObject.