# Swift - Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two protocols

Tags: swift

I'm trying to compare two protocol types using the reference comparison (`===`). When I do I get (where `Foo` is a protocol):

```
Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'Foo' operands
```

I understand why [`==` won't work without conforming to `Equatable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325725), but in this case I'm using `===`, which is just an address comparison.

Comment: Are these class protocols? `===` will work only on class types, not on value types (structs, enums). If the protocol is not declared as class protocol, it won't work because the compiler can't know that you are comparing classes and not structs.

Comment: @Sulthan  Good point. But won't all protocols eventually be conformed to by a class?

Comment: No, since structs for example can conform to protocols as well

Answer (score 13):

Let's show the problem on declarations:

The `===` operator is declared for `AnyObject`.

```
public func ===(lhs: AnyObject?, rhs: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

What exactly is `AnyObject`? `AnyObject` is a protocol to which all classes automatically conform.

In Swift, there are not only class types, there are also value types, e.g structs and enums. All of them can conform to protocols but structs and enums do not conform to `AnyObject`. Since you have Java background, the behavior of value types is similar to primitive types in Java - they are passed by value (copying) and you don't usually get a reference to them.

When you are declaring a protocol, the compiler doesn't know whether it will be adopted by classes or structs.

```
protocol X {}

struct A: X {}

let x1: X = A()
let x2: X = A()

// PROBLEM - we cannot compare two structs by ===
if x1 === x2 {
}
```

That means we have to tell the compiler that the protocol can be adopted only by classes:

```
protocol X: AnyObject {}
```

or

```
protocol X: class {}
```

Then

```
class A: X {}  // can be adopted only by classes

let x1: X = A()
let x2: X = A()

// NO problem
if x1 === x2 {
}
```

Comment: You are not comparing using the protocol definition, only the class definition - you would need to cast or tell the compiler the type rather than letting it get inferred.

Comment: @OliverAtkinson You are right.

Comment: === operator is defined there, in AnyObject protocol. Still you are not able to create an instance of AnyObject. try to do it and let me know ...

Comment: "When you are declaring a protocol, the compiler doesn't know whether it will be adopted by classes or structs." But You can. protocol P: class {}

Comment: could you edit this answer so that after you declare the protocol X a class protocol, that you make A()  a class,  that is the only bit that is missing

Answer (score 3):

`===` comparator is for comparing references - since structs are value types they pass by value and do not have references. (essentially passing a struct just takes a copy)

Classes are pass by reference - the instance is stored in memory so you are able to use the `===` comparator.

So yes you can compare them, but you need to ensure the protocol is constrained to classes only.

e.g.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

protocol Foo: class {

}

class A: Foo {

}

class B: Foo {

}

let a: Foo = A()
let b: Foo = A()
let c: Foo = B()

a === a // true
a === b // false
a !== c // true
b === c // false
c === c // true
```

where

```
struct B: Foo {

}
```

would fail to compile

Comment: you compare references to instances os class, not protocol.

Comment: @user3441734 They are casted to the protocol type - you are telling the compiler that all you know about the variable is that it conforms to Foo. It doesn't know that a or b is of instance A.

Comment: "you are telling the compiler that all you know about the variable is that it conforms to Foo" that is true! but still you have instance of your class or struct etc. type.  check the .dynamicType of the variable which conform to protocol and you assigned its value to some class or struct etc.

Comment: underlying it will be checking it against class instances - but thats why we want to constrain it to classes because structs are value types and do not have a reference address. I'm not really sure what you are trying to get at here!

Comment: see example in my answer, which i put it there right now

Comment: please, give me one example how to create instance of protocol type. this is NOT possible! how you can compare two references to protocols if you are not able to make instance of it?

Comment: @user3441734 the question wasn't how to instantiate protocols but compare them

Comment: @OliverAtkinson to improve your answer, make b an object of class B(): Foo

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm not sure what it would add - were just testing reference equality not instance (or type) equality

Comment: @OliverAtkinson it will prove that you are comparing the reference  and that no class comparison is even done, since B will not conform to A, this way when anybody in the future sees this answer,  they can understand how it works a little better

Answer (score -6):

with === you can compare two references to some instances, but protocol type cannot be instantiated!

```
protocol P {}
class C: P{}
let c = C()
let p:P = C()
c.dynamicType // C.Type
p.dynamicType // C.Type
```

and

```
let p:P = P() // error !!!
```

You can tell the compiler that you protocol is class protocol

```
protocol P: class {}
class C: P{}
struct S: P{} // error: non-class type 'S' cannot conform to class protocol 'P'
```

to be sure there is no value type which conforms to it

see the last example

```
protocol P: class {}
class C: P{}
let c = C()
let p:P = c

p === c  // true !!
let p1:P = c

p === p1 // true !!!
```

the === operator works here

```
let c1 = C()
let p2:P = c1

p2 === p1 // false !!
```

Comment: you are kind of right, but at the same time this does not provide any help. Since you can still have instances of protocols by "downcasting" a instance of a class conforming to the protocol.

Comment: @luk2302 you can compare references to instances of class, not instances of protocol type. even though someone don't agree, that is the reality. you are not able to create a instance of protocol.

Comment: @luk2302 downcasting doesn't change dynamicType. downcasting can help you to work with the type as it is an instance of protocol (hiding all class or struct ... specific implementation), but you still have an instance of 'original' dynamicType

Comment: OK, dear downvoters, please provide me an example how to create reference to protocol. this should be the first step to compare two references

Comment: Although I have not down voted you yet, I believe you are getting down votes because you do not answer the question, you are just saying protocols do not have instances, which is not the problem here

Comment: @Knight0fDragon === operator compare references. reference means that you have an instance. you are not able to create an instance of protocol. that means, you are not able use === operator for protocols.

Comment: it does not matter if the protocol itself is an instance,  The point is to check if  2 instances that conform to a protocol are the same instance, so if class A and class B both conform to protocol P, they can still be compared to see if they are indeed the same instance

Comment: @Knight0fDragon you can, but you are responsible to cast the reference to the same reference type.

Comment: that is not the same thing,  you can't cast class B to class A,  you will get errors

Comment: @Knight0fDragon see my last example, please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99549/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-user3441734).